# Using a nested foreach statement to display html data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have two models below.

```
        public class CustMaster
        {
            public string  FirstName { get; set; }
            public string  LastName { get; set; }
            public List<DetailsInfo> GetDetails { get; set; }        
        }

        public class DetailsInfo
        {
            public string  OrderId { get; set; }
            public string  OrderDescription { get; set; }
            public string  OrderStatus { get; set; }
            public string  Price { get; set; }        
        }
```

I use this model in my view to display the result in my html section

```
        @model IEnumerable<Tester.Domain.GenClasses.CustMaster>
```

Data is returned in this format

```
        Row 0
          -FirstName
          -LastName
          -GetDetails
                -Row 0
                  -OrderId
                  -OrderDescription
                  -OrderStatus
                  -Price                      
                -Row 1
                  -OrderId
                  -OrderDescription
                  -OrderStatus
                  -Price
        Row 1
          -FirstName
          -LastName
          -GetDetails
                -Row 0
                  -OrderId
                  -OrderDescription
                  -OrderStatus
                  -Price

                -Row 1
                  -OrderId
                  -OrderDescription
                  -OrderStatus
                  -Price
```

I want to be able to display data in my html i.e loop through the entire main 
list and write out the inner data. I am thinking it should be like the code below.
Is this correct? What will the parent foreach look like? Will this be a foreach or 
a for statement? Please assist.

```
      @foreach(what goes here?)
      {
        @foreach (var m in CustMaster)
        {
            <ul>
            <li>                  
            </li>

            @foreach (var d in m.GetDetails)
            {

               <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li> </li>
                        <li> </li>
                        <li> </li>
                        <li> </li>                                  
                    </ul>
                </li>

              }
            </ul>
        } 
      }
```

Comment: It returns the model CustMaster populated with data which is fine.

Comment: As a general note `foreach` statement works on  objects that implements a `IEnumerable` interface.
Then the answer is .. it depends on how the collections of `CustMaster` objects is defined.

Comment: Did you see this line. @model IEnumerable<Tester.Domain.GenClasses.CustMaster>

Comment: Everything is listed in my question. Did you read my question? Thanks.

Comment: then the answer is .. yes .. you can use foreach.

Comment: Fine thanks. How do I write the parent foreach is the question?

Comment: you got the answer just below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach(var c in Model)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. So this will loop through the list right?

Comment: It should loop over your IEnumerable<Tester.Domain.GenClasses.CustMaster>

Comment: Thanks. I will try it now.

Comment: Actually I got it to work without the outermost foreach statement. It wasn't necessary.